# WPF TabIndex doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel, tabindex, groupbox

I have a Problem with setting up the `TabIndexes` correctly. I have a `Usercontrol` with a `GroupBox`.

```
<GroupBox KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" TabIndex="0">
        <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue">
                <my:uscZeitraum TabIndex="1" />
                <Label />
                <ComboBox TabIndex="2" />
                <Label />
                <ComboBox TabIndex="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88" />
                <Label />
                <ComboBox TabIndex="4" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="67" />
                <Label />
                <ComboBox TabIndex="5" IsEditable="True" GotFocus="cboVorgang_GotFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue">
                <Label />
                <ComboBox TabIndex="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="192" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                <Label />
                <ComboBox TabIndex="7" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="225" />
                <Label />
                <ComboBox IsEditable="True" TabIndex="8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="67" />
                <Label />
                <ComboBox IsEditable="True" TabIndex="9" Width="80" />                                 
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
```

The first `Control` is also a `UserControl` but this works like I want to. But if I reach the third `ComboBox` in the first `StackPanel` it just starts at the beginning again. It doesn't focus the fourth `ComboBox` and also doesn't jump into the second `Row`/`Stackpanel`. What could that be?

Comment: There must be some code in cboVorgang_GotFocus which is doing that. Could you share the code in cboVorgang_GotFocus?

Comment: Thanks you already led me on the right tracks. In the Function the Focus is manually set to a different Control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be some code in cboVorgang_GotFocus which is doing that. The code written there would be changing the tab order.